# Use of array of zero length

Tags: java, arrays

For example we can construct such an array like this:

```
 new ElementType[0];
```

I seen such a construct, but I don't understand why this might be useful.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

An example. Say, you have a function

```
public String[] getFileNames(String criteria) {
```

to get some filenames. Imagine that you don't find any filenames satisfying criteria. What do you return? You have 2 choices - *either return null*, or *0-sized array*.

The variant with *0-sized array* is better, because your caller doesn't need to check for **NULL** and can process the array in a consistent way - say, in a loop (which would be empty in this case).

There's a chapter on this in [Effective Java, Item 27](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&lpg=PP1&dq=effective%2Bjava&pg=PA134)

Comment: To be sure: if the code is meant to be used on "lower layers", `null` is way more performant. Also see 3rd paragraph of https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Answer (score 15):

It's easier to work with than `null` in many cases, where `null` is the obvious alternative.

Suppose you want to return an `Iterable<String>` containing (say) a list of relevant filenames... but there aren't any for some reason. You *could* return `null` to indicate that, but then the caller has to special-case that. Instead, if you return an empty collection, the caller can still use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (String file : getFiles())
```

So why use an empty array instead of an empty `ArrayList` or something similar? Arrays are a fixed size, so an empty array is effectively immutable. That means you can keep a single value and return it to whoever you like, knowing they can't possibly do anything with it. That can be very useful in some situations.

Answer (score 4):

it is a replacement for null since you don't need to check for null before use it.
More formally it is a special case of [special case design pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html) (check also Null Object).

Another idiomatic use is collections **toArray**:

```
List<String> list = new ... ;
// fill the list
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Note that in the second case, any `String[]` would work just as well; it just needs an instance of the type you want to convert it to.