# zero length arrays

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the usage of array of zero length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036666/what-is-the-usage-of-array-of-zero-length)

What is the purpose of zero length arrays.Are they of any use or just like that because the syntax allows?

Comment: Note: As zero length arrays are immutable they are all equal for a given type and you can usually use a constant zero for `int[0]` for example. The only exception is if you have used a zero length array as a lock but this is bad idea IMHO.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have a function that takes an array, and you want to give it an array with nothing in it, you pass an zero-length array.

If you read an array from an external source, and it happens to not have any items, you'll get an zero-length array.

Comment: Using this approach means far less null checks are required

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you mean in Java, you can iterate over zero-length arrays without any problem but you can't do this, if the variable is set to `null`.

```
String[] myArr = new String[0];
for (String str : myArr) {
  // do something here
}
```

If you set `myArr` to `null` instead, you'd get a `NullPointerException` in this loop.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason not to allow zero-length arrays and supporting them avoid having to special case many things.

For example: What should the compiler pass to `varArg` if a method defined like this:

```
public void foo(String arg1, String... varArg);
```

is called like this:

```
foo("bar");
```

Also, what should be the return value of `"".toByteArray("UTF-8")`?

Forbidding zero-length arrays would complicate the language considerably while adding very little advantage.

Answer (score 5):

They let you keep an API consistent while avoiding null values.  For instance, say you have a method that returns an array of something.  If there are no valid results, you would return a zero length array.  If instead you were forced to return null to signal this, the client code would have to treat the two cases differently.  With the zero length array, code like the following still works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   // do something with the array entries
}
```

If array.length == 0, then the body of the loop is never entered.

Answer (score 1):

It avoids from having to check for null if the precondition is that an array is always present.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of an object with no methods, members, or behavior? An array is just a pointer to a contiguous block of memory, so 0 is a valid length.