# Use of Array of length 0?

Tags: java, arrays

```
char[] arrNew = new char[0];
System.out.println(arrNew.length);  // length = 0
arrNew[0]='c'; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException .
```

In the above code as you can clearly see there is no point in having an array of size 0. As far as I can see there is no practical usage of 0 size array. Can someone explain why the compiler allows creation of 0 length array. And also how is a 0 length array different from an array initialized to null? (i.e, is memory allocated to it as if it were a normal array?). I am sorry if this question seems stupid.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036666/use-of-array-of-zero-length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can return an empty array instead of null from a method, this is called Null object design pattern. Consider the following code

```
    Person[] res = find(name);
    for(String e : res) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

if find() does not find anyone it returns an empty array. If find returned null then code would need to treat it as a special case.

We should keep in mind that empty array is immutable so it is logical to use a singleton instead of creating it each time

```
private static final Person[] NULL = new Person[0];

Person[] find(String name) {
     ...
     if (notFound) {
           return NULL;
     }
     ...
```

Comment: Makes sense.. But will memory be allocated to the 0 length array?

Comment: @TheLostMind yes it will be allocated

Comment: @Aniket - first of all why??... There is not a single cell to point to , so how much will be allocated?..

Comment: @TheLostMind Are you aware that array is a subclass of `Object`? How much do you think is allocated for a `new Object()`? At least that much is allocated for an array.

Comment: An array has a structure, in an abstract way, stores the meta data as the number of cells. The memory for that will be allocated, but just that the number of cells(`length` technically) will be 0

Comment: Well.. Thanks for mentioning Null Object Design pattern. I have used it (as a good programming practice), but never gave much thought to it actually. (There had to be a reason..the designers of java were/are smart . :P).

Comment: Depending on usage, the `NULL` singleton may even decrease performance and have no influence on the memory footprint. This would happen if the empty array is used without escaping the method. Escape analysis will then eliminate its allocation and access to it will be faster due to the typical CPU cache misses caused by dereferencing the `NULL` singleton.

Answer (score 5):

It's best not to return null from a method that returns an array type. Always returning an array, even if the array has zero length, greatly improves the generality of algorithms. If you anticipate that your methods will return zero-length arrays frequently, you might be concerned about the performance implications of allocating many such arrays. To solve that problem, simply allocate a single array, and always return the same one, for example:

```
private static final int ZERO_LENGTH_ARRAY[] = new int[0];
```

This array is immutable (it can't be changed), and can be shared throughout the application.

So in Null Object pattern, a null object replaces check of NULL object instance. Instead of putting if check for a null value, Null Object reflects a do nothing relationship. Such Null object can also be used to provide default behaviour in case data is not available.

Comment: +1 If you mention the "Null object design pattern", you may garner more upvotes. The SO community apparently thinks that the ability to write "design pattern" makes you one of the demi-gods of software development :)

Answer (score 1):

Compiler allows because that code its within the rules of the language.

And no, they are both not the same. If it were the same, you would get a `NullPointerException` rather than `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Ya.. I know, but is memory allocated for it??.. If yes, then whats the point in allocating it? (we will not be able to store anything inside it ..)

Comment: `null` references have nowhere to point to. `0` length arrays have a place to point to and can be derefrenced without running into `NullPointerException`. See @EvgeniyDorofeev's explanation on "why" of it

Answer (score 1):

It can be of use, if you have a function returning reference to array, and if you have nothing to return then you might consider its better to return 0 length array than a null. If null were returned you would have to check this function for both null value, and if range is correct, if you return 0 length array - then you might only check the if range is correct - ie. in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Zero-length arrays are rarely "required," but are more often used simply to show that there is no data being passed to a method.

in java the memory allocation can be dynamic in nature. The java array enables the user to store values of the same type in contiguous memory allocations. Arrays are always a fixed length abstracted data structure which can not be altered when required. It just occupies the memory.