# Why java allows zero length index(in middle) array?

Tags: java, arrays

`javac` allows below syntax,

```
int[][][] i = new int[4][0][2];
```

which has zero length index that prevents access beyond.

1) There is no way to access third dimension. zero length dimension as last dimension(`int[][][] i = new int[4][2][0];`) looks fine.

2) It is not possible to write an initialiser for a multi-dimensional array with a zero length dimension unless that dimension is the last( for instance `int[2][3][0]`).

Why java allows such syntax?

*Note: this question has nothing to do with `int[0]`*

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of array of zero length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036666/use-of-array-of-zero-length)

Comment: @m0skit0 I know the advantages of zero length arrays, please read the question

Comment: I think this is exactly the main thing, why it should be possible - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1036699/4892907

Comment: It's not just in "the middle". You can define a one dimentional array with zero length just as well: `int[] a = new int[0];`

Comment: @overexchange That actually answers your question. Think about it.

Comment: @m0skit0 When there is no way to access third dimension in `int[4][0][2]`, what is the idea to allow such syntax? `int[4][0]` make sense to me.

Comment: Preventing constructing such arrays would complicate the language with little added benefit; the compiler could very well check this, but really, would it be worth implementing such a feature?

Comment: @MickMnemonic FIrstly, Can you help me understand if this is duplicate question? I am still not clear, why is this duplicate?

Comment: Because the reason to not have a third dimension is the same as not having the first dimension since allocation can be dynamic, eg. `new int[a][b][c]`. However in the end it's just a design decision.

Answer (score 3):

Because [nothing in the `multianewarray` bytecode instruction prevents you from doing so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

There is really no better answer than that... The fact is that for any `X`, even if `X` is a primitive, then `X[]` is a class, `X[][]` is a class and so on; and you are free to choose the "dimensions" of the array.

Note how declaring a `X[n][]` and a `X[n][m]` array differ: in the first you'll declare a `anewarray` of `X[]` whereas in the second you'll declare a `multianewarray` of `X`.

Of course, in `X[m][n][p]`, there is no possibility to ever have a "third dimension" (p) if `n` is 0, but... Well, the programmer knows what he's doing, right?

Just another bizarreness of arrays in the JVM... Think nothing of it except that "it can happen" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @m0skit0 - I think this is a duplicate questions. However I will give a brief answer anyways.

Basically its an alternative for null.  Consider simply, you have a method that returns an array, but it has no value to return. You could return null, but then you have to check for null in your code. On the other hand, you could return a 0 length array. Code such as the follows would automatically be skipped.

```
for(int p = 0; p < array.length; p++) {
```

Comment: This answers another question.

Comment: Are you referring to the difference between a 0-length array and multidimensional array with a single (or multiple) 0-length indices? If so I don't feel they are, not to mention the answer provided also answers both. Again - Presuming this is what you are referring to.

Comment: the `int[0]` syntax is legal and has it's purpose, which you have explained. But `int [0][1]` looks absurd. The question is: why is it legal indeed?

Comment: It just looks absurd, but it isn't.

Comment: I just imagine a similar situation to cover both cases - e.g. reading in information that could end up being a 1D or 2D array. But I do see your point.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do perfectly acceptable stuff like:

```
public static final int[][][] EMPTYARRAY = new int[0][0][0];
```

note also things a much worse than you suppose because this is also legal:

```
public static final int[] SCREWEDARRAY = new int[-1];
```

which causes a **runtime** error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not just in "the middle". You can easily define a one dimensional array just as easily:

`int[] a = new int[0];`

Second, an array with zero length is a bit like an empty collection. It's a legal data structure which might be returned by a method, but which happens to be empty.